# How to traverse the result of tf.unqiue?

Tags: tensorflow

After invoking `tf.unqiue`, the shape of tensor will be unknown, but I want to traverse the result of `tf.unqiue`

Suppose `tensor = tf.unqiue(...)`

I have tried:

- for i in tf.range(tf.shape(tensor)[0])
- tf.unstack(tensor, num=tf.shape(tensor)[0])
- tf.split(tensor, num_or_size_splits=tf.shape(tensor)[0])

All of them can't work, because these functions all need static shape or num/num_or_size_splits = integer? So how can I traverse `tensor`?

## Update

### Example

I have two 1-D tensor with the same shape

`x=[1,3,2,1,3]
y=[3,6,5,8,9]`

I want to do like this:

`x_u = unique(x) # [1,3,2]`

get bool_mask, and slice y

`for i in x_u:
    y[x == i]`

- when i=1, y[x==i]=y[[True,False,False,True,False]], and I can get y[0] and y[3]
- when i=3, I can get y[1] and y[4]
- when i=2, I can get y[2]

### Solution

After some trials, that may be a solution.

Try to use `tf.while_loop`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.constant(np.array([1,3,2,1,3]), dtype='int32')
y = tf.constant(np.array([3,6,5,8,9]), dtype='int32')

x_u, _ = tf.unique(x)
n = tf.shape(x_u)[0]
for_i = tf.constant(0)
re = tf.constant([], dtype=tf.int32)
cond = lambda i, res: i<n

def body(i, res):
    x_0 = tf.slice(x_u, [i], [1])
    selected = tf.boolean_mask(y, tf.equal(x_0, x))
    return i+1, tf.concat([res, selected], axis=0)

op = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [for_i, re], shape_invariants=[for_i.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None])])
print(op[1].shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(op[1]))
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'traverse' ? Do you just want to print each element or apply a function on each ?

Comment: No, I want to use each element of  `tf.unqiue(...)`, like `for i in tf.unqiue(...)`, each element may be used differently. If I know the shape of `tensor=tf.unqiue(...)`,  I can use `for i in range(tensor.shape[0])` and do whatever I want to do.

Comment: Do you want to apply Tensorflow functions on each elements or Numpy functions ? Because in the first case you can use tf.map_fn and in the second return your unique Tensor with sess.run(..) and then use it outside your Tensorflow session.

Comment: tf.map_fn can't use unknown shape tensor, if you pass `tf.unique` into tf.map_fn, it will raise an error, and I don't want to go out of computation graph, so you should not use `sess.run(tf.unique)` to get the shape.

Comment: Thank you for the update :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.constant(np.random.randn(200), dtype='float32')
b = tf.unique(a)
print b[0] #Tensor("Unique:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32)

c = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x*x, b[0])

init  = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
d = sess.run(c)

print d
```

And it's working without knowing the shape of 'b' here. Be careful, tf.unique is returning a tuple (Tensor, Tensor) with the values and their indicies.

**Update**

This is the only way I found to do this, your result cannot have an insconsistent shape in Tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.constant(np.array([1,3,2,1,3]), dtype='int32')
y = tf.constant(np.array([3,6,5,8,9]), dtype='int32')

x_u = tf.unique(x)

eq = tf.equal(x, tf.expand_dims(x_u[0],1)) 

y_masked = y*tf.cast(eq, tf.int32)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
e = sess.run(y_masked)

print e
```

`tf.boolean_mask` can be used as well but you are going to get a flat output.

**Last Update**

This is what you want, way faster than what you proposed and it was already explained the line just above.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.constant(np.array([1,3,2,1,3]), dtype='int32')
y = tf.constant(np.array([3,6,5,8,9]), dtype='int32')

x_u, _ = tf.unique(x)

eq = tf.equal(x, tf.expand_dims(x_u,1)) 

y_tiled = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(y, 0), [tf.shape(x_u)[0], 1])
y_masked = tf.boolean_mask(y_tiled, eq)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
e = sess.run(y_masked)

print e
```

Comment: I have also tried, it can work. But in my impression, `tf.map_fn` will unpack the elems passed into `map_fn` along axis-0, but I have tried `tf.unstack` can't work when the tensor shape is unknown, so I'm puzzled

Comment: see [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py#L372) of `map_fn`, it use `unstack`, it is amazing.

Comment: `tf.map_fn` will pack the the result of `fn`, so it requires the shape of result returned by `fn` is the same, but my update is not the same, I think it is hard to solve.

Comment: Wait a bit, i'm searching for a solution, so for an output you want res= [[y[0], y[3]],[y[1],y[4]],[y[2]]], right ?

Comment: I may use [y[0], y[3]] to do other things, so I should iterate  [[y[0], y[3]],[y[1],y[4]],[y[2]]], it means I should know the length, but the shape is unknown

Comment: But this is what you want right ? Just wanna know this :)

Comment: The problem with this kind of Tensor is that each element does not have the same shape, so it can't be defined by a Tensor but I can try to return an array of Tensor. Is that ok ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157783/discussion-between-anthony-damato-and-gaussclb).

Comment: If you can get a list of tensor, I think it is ok, because I can get the length of list.

Comment: I'm sorry, you just get `y_masked`, but the shape is (?,5), so it is not what I want. I can't iterate along the row of `y_masked` and use each row to do other things.

Comment: you can think as that I want to get a list, like [ fun([y[0],y[3]]),  fun([y[1],y[4]]), fun([y[2]]) ], `fun` is a function which takes a list  as parameter, but may return different shape tensors, it just mean I need to iterate.

Comment: I know what you want but this is impossible since the shapes are inconsistent.

Comment: What I provided is [[y[0], 0, 0, y[3], 0], [0, y[1], 0, 0, y[4]], [0,0,y[2],0,0]], in your `fun` just discard the zeros. And yes you can iterate it using `tf.map_fn`.

Comment: but the shape of result of `fn` is different, such as shape_0=[3], shape_1=[4], so tf.map_fn can't work.

Comment: Try to make it invariant

Comment: So, what exactly do you wanna do in your function?

Comment: I have tried to use `tf.while_loop`, it can work, but coding is too hard. For my example see my solution update.

Comment: I can do whatever in my `body` function, and the returned result will be concate along axis-0, and I just want the result of concat, so it can work. Thanks for your insistent effort.

Comment: Are you serious ? Did you even read my answer ? I told you to use tf.boolean mask if you want a flat output, it's way faster than what you implemented and less fastidious.

Comment: Your last updation is not what I want, you just output `[3 8 6 9 5]`, not `[[3,8], [6,9], [5]]`, I need to use `[3,8]`, `[6,9]`, `[5]` to get tensor with `shape=[N, 4]`, N is different. So you should not use `tf.map_fn`, but `tf.while_loop` can use int  scalar tensor as looping upper bound, so I can get three tensors with shape `[N_1, 4]`, `[N_2, 4]`, `[N_3, 4]`, and concat them along axis-0, this isn't your last updation can achieved.